# Android locale: detect all chinese language locale

Tags: android, locale, chinese-locale

I've set language of my device in chinese (i hope!) and if i call

```
return Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
```

i obtain

```
zh_zh
```

Now i've noticed that there's different type of chinese language that user can set on his device, and i need to detect all of it. Which are the other value returned by getLanguage() for different chinese types?

Comment: Strangely when I call this I get zh, not zh_zh, to get the specifics I must call getDefault().getCountry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a complete list of language codes here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ee825488(v=cs.20).aspx

These are all the chinese variations:

```
zh-CN   Chinese - China 
zh-HK   Chinese - Hong Kong 
zh-MO   Chinese - Macau  
zh-SG   Chinese - Singapore 
zh-TW   Chinese - Taiwan    
zh-CHS  Chinese (Simplified)         
zh-CHT  Chinese (Traditional)
```

Comment: This does not apply to android.

Comment: The language codes are an international standard, that Android does follow too.

Comment: In Android, you may use underscore instead of hyphen.  For example, when `zh-HK` doesn't work, try `zh_HK`.